# Get options sent to pug with space in the name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to send JSON options into a pug file with a space in the attribute names.

For example, inside an express get request:

```
let json = {"Attribute Name With Spaces": "Value"}
res.render('loader.pug', json);
```

How do I access this data in the pug file?  It is difficult to change the format of the json because it is external and not something I made myself.

Comment: What use case are you trying to solve with this? In order to use the variable in your template, you'd need to know what it was so why provide one with a difficult name in the first place?

Comment: @Phil the json is coming from a REST api and it is more elegant if I can just send the data directly rather than do a lot of reformatting just to remove spaces. I didn’t know if there was some environment variable that I could just do something like params[‘variable name’] in the pug file, but I couldn’t find one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pug makes *locals* available under the `locals` property so you can simply use the following...

```pug
h1= locals["Attribute Name With Spaces"]
p Here's the var #{locals["Attribute Name With Spaces"]}
```

I couldn't find any official documentation for this so it might not always be a reliable option.

---

Another option to make this easier would be to simply bundle all your `json` properties under a single object...

```js
res.render("loader.pug", { props: json });
```

Then you can use something like this

```pug
h1= props["Attribute Name With Spaces"]
p #{props["Attribute Name With Spaces"]}
```

---

Alternately, transform your object to normalise the keys

```js
res.render(
  "loader.pug",
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(json).map(([key, val]) => [key.replaceAll(" ", "_"), val])
  )
);
```

and use

```pug
h1= Attribute_Name_With_Spaces
```

Comment: I love the first solution. It’s super simple and the kind of thing that makes me feel stupid for not coming up with that myself. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLewis I found another way